# Can vehicles be instructed to drive on the left side of the road rather than the right?

Tags: simcity-2013

Does Simcity take into account different regions driving on different sides of the road?

i.e. I live in a country where we drive on the left. This means that all my city-planning skills will default to making things easy for left-hand turns instead of right-hand turns, etc.

Comment: My game has sims driving on the right.  If yours drive on the left - then we have an answer between us.

Comment: @DavidB - I haven't started playing it yet. With all the launch debacles I've decided to hold off on trying, instead collecting a bunch of brownie points with the wife by doing housework rather than waiting for a progress meter. I shall then trade in the brownie points for extra game time once everything is stable. The joys of being an adult with a family!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Sims drive on the right -- I'm also based in an area where driving on the Left is the social norm; yet my sims seem intent on doing it wrong.

Comment: EA and Maxis are both American game studios, something like that, would have to be thought of when programming certain elements.

Comment: @Ramhound - sure, but in SC4 the cars would change depending on which region you bought the game in